# Как вставить "тишину" а аудио дорожку ffmpeg concat

Tags: linux, аудио, ffmpeg

**Добрый день.**

Есть набор видео файлов MP4 которые объединяю в один c наложением лого. Все хорошо, но некоторые файлы, не имеют звуковой дорожки. Как добавить тишину в аудио дорожку обедненного файла?

Система:
ffmpeg version 2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Команда:

```
ffmpeg -re  -auto_convert 1 -safe 0 -f concat -i mylist.txt  -i qr.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-15:15"  -c:v libx264 -g 40 -keyint_min 1 -vsync 1 -c:a aac  -ar 48000 -ac 2 -strict -2 -af aresample=async=1000  OUTPUT.mp4
```

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/579008/454489